# The meaning of "if I could get past the crusty edges"

Tags: definition

What is the meaning of "if I could get past the crusty edges" in this context:

> There on the counter sat a scrumptious-looking pan of freshly baked brownies. Well, they looked good **if you could get past the crusty edges**, which I was okay with at the moment. Without bothering to say hello to my mother, I dug in.

This passage is from the book *[Fire in Frost](https://books.google.com/books?id=bibxDQAAQBAJ&dq=crusty%20edges%20fire%20in%20frost&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*.

I want to know what does the phase exactly mean here. What is meant by "get past the crusty edges"?

Comment: Please, include more details as to what you don't understand in that sentence.

Comment: Have you eaten cooked brownies? They're baked.

Answer (score 1):

Brownies are a type of cake. They are chocolate flavoured and usually sticky and quite heavy.

Apparently, these cakes have "crusty edges" that is the edges of these brownies are have become hard (probably due to overbaking). The writer doesn't like the hard edge of brownies.

But if you can eat (or remove) the edge then the rest of the brownie is delicious. The writer will put up with the crusty edge now, so he starts eating the brownies (he "digs in").

Comment: So does he star eating edges or the other part

Comment: You can't eat the middle without first getting past the crusty edge. Most likely he just eats the crust. But it doesn't really matter. The point is "Without bothering to say hello to my mother, I dug in."